# CUDAfy.NET giving Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, cudafy.net

I've added a reference to the [CUDAfy.NET](http://cudafy.codeplex.com/) library via NuGet.

```
<package id="CUDAfy.NET" version="1.12.4695.21111" targetFramework="net45" />
```

When I run my program, I hit a `Win32Exception`:

> The system cannot find the file specified

This happens on the first actual line of the program:

```
CudafyModule km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy();
```

There's no indication from the exception object as to what file they're attempting to load.

How can I get past this problem?

**EDIT**

I see the same exception when running the bundled examples from the Codeplex download in VS2010 using .NET 4.0.

The strack trace is:

```
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Cudafy.CudafyModule.Compile(eGPUCompiler mode, Boolean deleteGeneratedCode)
at Cudafy.Translator.CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(ePlatform platform, eArchitecture arch, Version cudaVersion, Boolean compile, Type[] types)
at Cudafy.Translator.CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(ePlatform platform, eArchitecture arch, Type[] types)
at Cudafy.Translator.CudafyTranslator.Cudafy()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting VS to break on thrown exceptions shows the `ProcessStartInfo` object at the top of the stack in the locals pane of the debugger.

The relevant properties are:

```
FileName = nvcc
Arguments = -m64 -arch=sm_12 "c:\<path>\CUDAFYSOURCETEMP.cu" -o "c:\<path>\CUDAFYSOURCETEMP.ptx" --ptx
```

Some information from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202792/Using-Cudafy-for-GPGPU-Programming-in-NET) explains that the *CUDA Toolkit* must be installed. Fair enough.

> Ensure that the C++ compiler (cl.exe) is on the search path. This set-up of NVCC is actually the toughest stage of the whole process, so please persevere. Read any errors you get carefully - most likely they are related to not finding cl.exe or not having either 32-bit or 64-bit CUDA Toolkit.

That article discusses version 4 of the toolkit, but version 5 is available now and supported since CUDAfy v1.1.

Download from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Note that the 64-bit version of the CUDA Toolkit 5.0 is a 942 MB download. If you install everything you'll need an additional 2815 MB. The toolkit alone requires 928 MB.

**EDIT** After installing the CUDA Toolkit 5.0, the program failed with a `CudafyCompileException` at the same source line:

> Compilation error: nvcc : fatal error : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH

Searching my system drive:

```
C:\>dir /s cl.exe
```

This shows many different versions of the compiler/linker, both from VS 10.0 and 11.0. Apparently only `cl.exe` versions 9 and 10 are supported, so I opted for the VS10.0 amd64 version, I included the following in my `PATH` environment variable:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64

Your path may be different, depending upon your CPU. I recommend running the search to see your options.

Note that you will have to restart VS after changing the `PATH` environment variable if you already have it open.

After taking these steps, my basic program ran successfully.

Comment: Good evening, ive run into the same problem but im not 100% sure what you mean by the following "I included the following in my PATH environment variable:" could you please expand on this? Where abouts is the Path environment variable, is it a setting in VS? +1's btw :).

Comment: @HansRudel, the PATH environment variable is a system-wide setting that tells your computer where to look for programs that are requested without explicit paths. Perhaps [this question](http://superuser.com/q/284342/31787) will provide you with more information.

Comment: Thanks very much for the link, makes a bit more sense now. I had posted a question on SO, before i'd found this question, and someone filled in the gaps so I got it working this morning.

Answer (score 1):

This may also happen if you had at some point installed CUDA Toolkit v7.5, but realized that the most recent version of [CUDAfy](https://cudafy.codeplex.com/) supports CUDA 7.0. 
On uninstalling CUDA 7.5 from the control panel, some files/folders may still remain. You should delete these manually. You may use CUDAfyViewer to see which version of CUDA Toolkit is being accessed.