# Cudafy Win32Exception was unhandled: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, cudafy.net

I have been trying to get cudafy 1.29 to work. It supports Cuda toolkit 7.0.
I accidentally installed 7.5 first, uninstalled it and installed 7.0.

When I run the following line:

`km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy();`

I get the error mentioned above and shown below in the image. I have tried adding the following paths to the system environment variables:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64

But sadly enough, this doesn't work either.

[CUDAfy.NET giving Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338482/cudafy-net-giving-win32exception-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

[image: My error]

Comment: where does Cudafy say that it supports the 7.0 toolkit (but not 7.5) ?

Answer (score 1):

i had exactly the same problem and fix it by going to 
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\"
and deleting the v7.5 folder